# socketcan_bridge_node error handling

Tags: ros, can

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have an application that uses socketcan_bridge_node to do CAN communication. It works well, but occasionally the CAN network enters an error mode and the entire bridge node stops working. Is there a way I can detect this and reset the CAN?

The interesting thing is that, even if the node is in error mode, I can still send CAN packets on the same network without resetting using canutils (cansend, etc.). This tells me that the problem lies with the node not handling the error properly

I am not an expert on CAN networks however, so there might be something about CAN errors that I'm not understanding...

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/267980/socketcan_bridge_node-error-handling/) by [9a3eedi](https://answers.ros.org/users/27142/9a3eedi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 63 on 2017-08-03

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mathias Lüdtke](https://answers.ros.org/users/4094/mathias-l%C3%BCdtke/) on 2017-08-04**:
Which errors do you get?

**Comment by [9a3eedi](https://answers.ros.org/users/27142/9a3eedi/) on 2017-08-07**:
I'm getting "controller problems". It's really hard to isolate though, it only seems to happen when a microcontroller (not the computer running ROS) in the CAN network starts controlling a motor, and outdoors (hot weather) not indoors. Either way, I just want to be able to recover as a workaround.

**Comment by [peterlin300](https://answers.ros.org/users/25026/peterlin300/) on 2017-08-07**:
HI!
I also want to use ros socketcan_interface to communicate with the robot.
i.e. subscribe data and send it to my microcontroller by USB-CAN.
But I don't have any idea,can you tell me maybe how should i do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is no way to read the error state from the `socketcan_bridge` nodes or some sort of recover mechanism.

I have filed an [issue](https://github.com/ros-industrial/ros_canopen/issues/244) to track this.

`SocketCAN` has different error notfications and `socketcan_interface` treats all as errors. The higher-level node (e.g. `socketcan_bridge_node`) is supposed to handle them.

In general you should not get any errors, otherwise something is wrong with your network, your settings or your load is too high.

---

Originally posted by [Mathias Lüdtke](https://answers.ros.org/users/4094/mathias-l%C3%BCdtke/) with karma: 1596 on 2017-08-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [9a3eedi](https://answers.ros.org/users/27142/9a3eedi/) on 2017-08-07**:
There's definitely something wrong in the network, but I was at least hoping there's a way to recover for now until I figure out what the problem was. Thanks for filing the issue. I might actually even fix it myself.

**Comment by [Mathias Lüdtke](https://answers.ros.org/users/4094/mathias-l%C3%BCdtke/) on 2017-08-07**:
You can read (only) the error frames with `candump -l any,0~0,#FFFFFFFF`.
(see `/usr/include/linux/can/error.h` for the layout)

**Comment by [Mathias Lüdtke](https://answers.ros.org/users/4094/mathias-l%C3%BCdtke/) on 2017-08-07**:
The `can::DriverInterface` class (base of `ThreadedSocketCANInterface`) provides a `recover` function for soft errors. For hard errors the kernel interface needs to be restarted (see https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/can.txt)